# How do I set wait_timeout to unlimited in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How do I set wait_timeout to unlimited in mysql?

Comment: You can not set the wait_timeout to unlimited.

Answer (score 6):

1. Edit `my.cnf` (the MySQL configuration file).

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   ```
2. Locate the timeout configuration and adjust it to fit your server.

   ```
   [mysqld]
   wait_timeout = 31536000
   interactive_timeout = 31536000
   ```
3. Save the changes and exit the editor.
4. Restart MySQL to apply the changes as follows:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
   ```

Comment: That is setting it to the max allowed value (in seconds). High, yes. But not unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I alter /etc/*/my.cnf, it would cause a lot of bugs.
So I change to use mysql command to change it.

1. open mysql 
   `sudo service mysql start`
2. open command window

   ```
   sudo mysql -u username -p
   ```
3. change the timeout

   ```
   SET @@GLOBAL.interactive_timeout=31536000
   ```
4. restart server

   ```
   sudo service mysql restart
   ```

> windows timeout default is 31536000, you can choose the time you like
>   And the way to see the timeout is `show global variables like 'wait_timeout'`